# Merging CVPixelBuffers

Tags: avfoundation, core-image, cgimage, ciimage

I have CVPixelBuffers of 2 images. I want to merge the two such that the second image is on top of the first one at the co-ordinates I want. Appreciate if anyone can guide me in that.

I don't want to use context draws as I'm trying to lower the CPU utilization. The images would be screenshots that gets processed so it's real-time and doing thousands of context draws increases CPU utilization.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Core Image to

1. create two CIImages from the CVPixelBuffers
2. combine the two using CISourceOverCompositing
3. use CIContext render:toCVPixelBuffer: to render the result into a third CVPixelBuffer

Comment: CIContext render:toCVPixelBuffer: is only available on iOS. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIContext_Class/

Comment: As of 10.11 render:toCVPixelBuffer: now exists.